# Define two objects with the same name in javascript

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to define two objects with the same name in javascript..
for example

```
var record = {

            id: some value,
            name: some value,
            subject: some value,
        };
```

and again

```
var record = {};
```

Comment: No, it isn't. You probably need an array of objects.

Comment: @Vohuman Is it possible in jquery...suppose we define a on method and inside it we create the first record object as shown and again inside the .submit we create the second empty object

Comment: Functions create a new scope. You can define variables in different scopes by using the same identifier. Please note that this doesn't mean that this is not syntactically possible. JavaScript allows you to type `var article = 'bar'; var article = 'foo'`, the point is the second variable resets the value and you will lose the `'bar'`.

Comment: @Vohuman thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

No and Yes

No if is global variable or you insert in the same group example:

```
if(){
 var record = {
 id: some value,
 name: some value,
 subject: some value,
 };
 var record = {};
}
```

Yes If you make local variable or insert in diferent groups like:

```
if(){
 var record = {
 id: some value,
 name: some value,
 subject: some value,
};
} else {
 var record = {};
}
```

Comment: Is it possible in jquery...suppose we define a on method and inside it we create the first record object as shown and again inside the .submit we create the second empty object

Comment: But the question it is about js :P

Comment: _nothing_ that's impossible in js is possible in jquery

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, a variable can be declared after it has been used.
In other words; a variable can be used before it has been declared.

You can declare a uniquie variable only in a scope. you must read java-script hoisting:

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp